# I am having problems in installing R packages. Whenever I tried to install, I get an error message of non-zero status. What is the reason?

Tags: r

I tried to install the rethinking R package. However, I could not install the package. Whenever I install, R downloads the package, but it couldn't install for some reason. I even tried the direct website for the package, yet I ended up with the same problem. I also tried another package, "timetk". However, I faced the same error. Let me know the problem. Thanks.

Code:

#1.

```
devtools::install_github("rmcelreath/rethinking")
Downloading GitHub repo rmcelreath/rethinking@HEAD
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\bondb\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2T4bd5\remotes1e442e155feb\rmcelreath-rethinking-3b48ec8/DESCRIPTION' (557ms)
-  preparing 'rethinking': (505ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'rethinking_2.13.tar.gz' (438ms)
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/bondb/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rethinking' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'rethinking'
    finding HTML links ... done
    AMTL                                    html  
    Achehunting                             html  
    Boxes                                   html  
    Crofoot                                 html  
    Dinosaurs                               html  
    Dissertations                           html  
    Fish                                    html  
    HMC2                                    html  
    HPDI                                    html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ...
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/bondb/R/win-library/4.0/rethinking'
Error: Failed to install 'rethinking' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/bondb/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2T4bd5/file1e44343fd58/rethinking_2.13.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

#2.

```
install_github("https://github.com/rmcelreath/rethinking/releases/tag/2.13", force = T)
Downloading GitHub repo rmcelreath/rethinking@2.13
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\bondb\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2T4bd5\remotes1e44223e4eb1\rmcelreath-rethinking-3b48ec8/DESCRIPTION' (511ms)
-  preparing 'rethinking': (549ms)
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (416ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'rethinking_2.13.tar.gz' (523ms)
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/bondb/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rethinking' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'rethinking'
    finding HTML links ... done
    AMTL                                    html  
    Achehunting                             html  
    Boxes                                   html  
    Crofoot                                 html  
    Dinosaurs                               html  
    Dissertations                           html  
    Fish                                    html  
    HMC2                                    html  
    HPDI                                    html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ...
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/bondb/R/win-library/4.0/rethinking'
Error: Failed to install 'rethinking' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/bondb/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2T4bd5/file1e44327c130/rethinking_2.13.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

#3.

```
install.packages("timetk")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/bondb/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://xcelab.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'http://xcelab.net/R/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
timetk  2.6.0  2.6.1             FALSE

installing the source package ‘timetk’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/timetk_2.6.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3793775 bytes (3.6 MB)
downloaded 3.6 MB

* installing *source* package 'timetk' ...
** package 'timetk' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'timetk'
    finding HTML links ... done
    between_time                            html  
    bike_sharing_daily                      html  
    box_cox_vec                             html  
    condense_period                         html  
    diff_vec                                html  
    filter_by_time                          html  
    filter_period                           html  
    fourier_vec                             html  
    future_frame                            html  
    is_date_class                           html  
    lag_vec                                 html  
    log_interval_vec                        html  
    m4_daily                                html  
    m4_hourly                               html  
    m4_monthly                              html  
    m4_quarterly                            html  
    m4_weekly                               html  
    m4_yearly                               html  
    mutate_by_time                          html  
    normalize_vec                           html  
    pad_by_time                             html  
    parse_date2                             html  
    finding level-2 HTML links ...
Error: unknown input format
* removing 'C:/Users/bondb/R/win-library/4.0/timetk'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘timetk’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What does `readRDS(file.path(.libPaths()[1], ".Meta", "links.rds"))` return? Do you get a message that "no such file exists" or do you get "unknown input format"?

Comment: This is what it returned: 
readRDS(file.path(.libPaths()[1], ".Meta", "links.rds")) 

Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/Users/bondb/R/win-library/4.0/.Meta/links.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Yes, I got "no such file or directory exists" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see the message "finding level-2 HTML links ...", the package builder is running `tools::findHTMLlinks(level=2)` to find links between help files. Normally the link information is cached as an RDS file inside the package. Here's a variation of the code that is run by the function that you can run to check where the error might be coming from

```
check_rds <- function(rds) {tryCatch({readRDS(rds); TRUE}, error=function(x) {FALSE})}

for (x in rev(dir(.libPaths(), full.names = TRUE))) {
  is_ok <- if (file_test("-f", f <- file.path(x, "Meta", "links.rds")))
    check_rds(f)
  else if (file_test("-f", f <- file.path(x, "Meta", "Rd.rds")))
    check_rds(f)
  else TRUE
  if (!is_ok) {
    print(paste("bad file", x, f)); 
  }
}
```

It should print all the bad RDS files it finds. If nothing is printed, then the error must be somewhere else. But if it does identify a bad file, then I would suggest uninstalling that particular package and reinstalling it.